# How to route an html form submit through a node.js server to update the value of a variable in a .js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module

Sorry if there are some basics I'm missing here, I'm quite new to this.

Let's say I have three files. server.js, index.html, module.js. I want data input in index.html to change a variable in module.js.
Basically I think the process should go:

- User submits a form (as an array) on index.html
- server.js receives this info and
- Routes a specific value from the array to update a variable in module.js

I've made it a little bit of the way there by using an XMLHttpRequest to POST from index.html.

```
function send(){
      var url = "/";
      var params = document.getElementsByName("data[]");
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);

      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      xhr.send(params);
    }
```

which server.js is listening for with

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  });
```

What I need help with is:

1. Specifying which value in the array should be passed along
2. Using this value to update a defined variable in module.js
3. (bonus) is there a way to refresh the instance of node to use the updated variable without ending the process and re-running node server.js?

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

#### Add and modify the code as needed.

index.html:

```
<input type="text" id="textinput" />

fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  body: document.getElementById("textinput").value,
});
```

server.js

```
let variable = 5;

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  variable = req.body
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, yes this works when I use a single value. Could you explain more about how it might work with an array?

Lets say there is a second input with id="textinput2". How would I best make an array out of these two values then use the value of "textinput" to define a first variable, and "textinput2" to define a second?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's the same concept. just use `fetch("/", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  body: [
   document.getElementById("textinput").value,
  document.getElementById("textinput2").value,
});`